# TensorFlowLiteSwift, TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps nightly clang error - undefined symbol _uprv_getICUData_conversion

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow-lite

I have been using `TensorFlowLiteSwift` and `TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps 0.0.1-nightly` for I have custom models in my project. The models are `SELECT_TF_OPS` enabled. But when I'm trying to build the app for iPhone, I'm getting this clang error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
 “_uprv_getICUData_conversion”, referenced from:
   openCommonData(char const*, int, UErrorCode*) in TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps(udata_2985644a25bfa5ed30c4cd35b64b13bb.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41948) on GitHub that nobody seems to have solved.

Is there a solution for this? Any workarounds?

Thanks!